# make sure atleast one checkbox is selected php

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a little mailing form with a few checkboxes. At least one of the boxes need to be selected before mailing should start.

My HTML:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='part1' name='box1' value='box1' checked>
<label for="part1">Voor Leden agenda</label>
<br/>
<input type='checkbox' id='part2' name='box2' value='box2' checked>
<label for="part2">Voor Leiding agenda</label>
<br/>
<input type='checkbox' id='part3' name='box3' value='box3' checked>
<label for="part3">Verhuur agenda</label>
<br/>
<button type='submit' name='send'/>send</button>
```

My PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['box1'])) {
    $box1 = 'yes';
} else {
    $box1 = 'No';
}
if (isset($_POST['box2'])) {
    $box2 = 'yes';
} else {
    $box2 = 'No';
}
if (isset($_POST['box3'])) {
    $box3 = 'yes';
} else {
    $box3 = 'No';
}
```

i would like to have a script that gives a message like below if no checkbox is selected:

```
if()
{
    echo "<p class='redfont'>no checkboxes are selected</p>";
    echo "<p><a href='javascript:history.back();'>Click to go back</a></p>";
}
```

**edit:**  how can I give this message with php, only if all boxes are unchecked

Comment: add an onclick to the checkboxes that will call out javascript fuction that checks if any checkboxes are checked if not set it checked again.

Comment: You have not asked a question. This is not a code writing service!

Comment: add an 'onsubmit' call to the form to check whether it's properly done. in the script return false if nothing is checked.

Comment: @RUJordan How to do this?

Comment: I just want to say that JQuery can be modified by the client so that it passes the validation and everything should be re-validated server-side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(!isset($_POST['box1']) && !isset($_POST['box2']) && !isset($_POST['box3']))
{
      // none is set
}
```

You could even apply De Morgan's law and write this equivalent expression

```
if(isset($_POST['box1']) || isset($_POST['box2']) || isset($_POST['box3']))
{
      // at least one of them is set
}
```

You could even send those 3 parameters to 1 `isset` call but then that would check if all of them are set, which is not your requirement.

Comment: The first code you typed was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST["box1"]) || isset($_POST["box2"]) || isset($_POST["box3"])) {
    if(isset($_POST['box1'])) {
        $box1 = 'yes';
    } else {
        $box1 = 'No';
    }
    if(isset($_POST['box2'])) {
        $box2 = 'yes';
    } else {
        $box2 = 'No';
    }
    if(isset($_POST['box3'])) {
        $box3 = 'yes';
    } else {
        $box3 = 'No';
    }
} else {
    echo "<p class='redfont'>no checkboxes are selected</p>";
    echo "<p><a href='javascript:history.back();'>Click to go back</a></p>";
}
```

Comment: "Try this" is not an explained answer.

Comment: If he has trouble understanding that, the only answer becomes "hire a programmer".

Comment: If he didn't have trouble understanding, he wouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: He just didn't think about it at first because he is new. Now he knows this is possible and it opens up a world of possibilities for him.

Comment: That's why he needs that little bit of explanation to help him learn ;)

Comment: Well if he has trouble, he can always comment and ask. Often times, by experience, the issues you have is merely ignorance of what is possible and no explanation is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This one is more readable I think:

```
$boxes = ['box1', 'box2', 'box3'];
$checked = [];

foreach($boxes as $box){
    if(isset($_POST[$box])){
        $checked[] = $box;
    }
}

if(count($checked) == 0){
    // no boxes checked
    echo "<p class='redfont'>no checkboxes are selected</p>";
    echo "<p><a href='javascript:history.back();'>Click to go back</a></p>";
}else{
    // at least one box is checked, you can do another foreach statement
        with the $checked variable to do stuff with the checked ones
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this for ANY number of checkboxes (Webistes are bound to expand), I assume all of you checkboxes are of the form box**i** :

```
if( strpos( implode(',' , array_keys($test)) , 'box' ) !== FALSE )
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this function in JQuery:

```js
jQuery.validation = function(){

    var verif = 0;
    $(':checkbox[id=list_exp]').each(function() { 
        if(this.checked == true){
            verif++
        }
    });

    if(verif == 0){
        alert("no checkboxes are selected");
        return false;
    }    
}
```